# Can't read files from Venix 80286 file system

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am trying to read a disk with a Venix 80286 file system. I need to copy some files from it.

PartedMagic keeps saying that the partition is "unknown". So, how can I read the files?

Comment: No Linux distribution supports all file systems. What problem are you trying to solve, really? Please remove your second question as it's too subjective.

Comment: ...And what is supported today isn't tomorrow (new technologies will be introduced etc)!

Comment: @slhck, i am trying to read a disk with files-system venix 80286. i need to copy some files from it. But parted magic keep saying partition "unknown". and don't really know which Linux dist opens it?

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You want to do X, but try solving it by asking for Y. Please ask the right question (about X) the next time. I edited your post to ask about your real question instead.

Comment: the edit made the question from "What?" to "OOH!"

Answer (score 1):

No operating system supports *all* file systems.

Check out this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems), the last table shows which OSs support which file systems.

As for which Linux distro is best, they are all equal for all intents and purposes.  Files system support is based on kernel version, or with extra software/drivers.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the list you linked to, linux supports all but four obscure filesystems!

Comment: @terdon - Linux has been ported to many of the machines that supported these file systems, so naturally the developers doing the port would include support for the file system that was supported by that machine's original OS.

Comment: Not counting of course, file systems too obscure for wikipedia and not notable enough. And that hobbyist filesystem that someone threw together drunk and... and...

Comment: Please see the updated post by the OP, which now asks about the real issue they're facing.